# How to load Android preferences before activity displays?

Tags: android, load, sharedpreferences

I'm building app with certain need to accept disclaimer and some other manifests.

So on the first start app works like this:

Splash screen -> Disclaimer -> Manifest -> Setup of the app -> My App

On every other load it goes directly to My App section.

Now, I've created activity called "setupCheck" and if first three screens are "used", it goes to "My App". That works fine, how ever even though I did not setup any layout and I did not setup "setContextView" in "setupCheck", I still receive ugly blank screen before my app load.

What's the right approach to load Sherd prefs without any screens visible, and then depending on true or false states go to Splash or go to My App.

Tnx for helping on this.

Edit:
Code in setup

```
boolean disclamerChecked = getPrefs.getBoolean("disclamer", true); 
boolean screeningChecked = getPrefs.getBoolean("screening", true); 
boolean splashChecked = getPrefs.getBoolean("splash", true); 
if (splashChecked == true) { 
    if (disclamerChecked == true) { 
        if (screeningChecked == true) { 
            Intent intent = new Intent( "mypackage.mypackage.SPLASH");
            startActivity(intent); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: The Splash screen will never show to the user after the first run?

Comment: Yes. As said, it is displayed only first time. Otherwise I would use splash screen to load settings, but now I have no clue how to load them and then jump to app directly.

Comment: So I might have misunderstood your problem. Is your problem that you have a black screen while you try to load the shared preferences? Or is it something else, then please specify further. I'll update the answer after.

Answer (score 0):

There will always be a screen before your app starts, but it is possible to change this with a tiled view of a full size image/full size solid color.

Your first view will not be shown before onCreate() comes to an end. So if you are doing a lot of processing in onCreate() then it will take a lot of time before the initial view is shown. This is also why it is recommended to do as much processing in a background thread instead of at start up.

Comment: Well, In my first onCreate I have nothing (for test purposes), and I do not have setContentView at all, but still white dialog appears on second, and then it goes as planned. If Background thread is needed, OK, but how to start background thread before actual app start? I'm quite fresh in this as you can see ;)

Comment: Which activity is first launched from your manifest? Also what do you mean with " but still white dialog appears on second, and then it goes as planned"

Comment: Please add updates to your original question using the edit function. Posting large unformatted comments is not good practice

Comment: @Balkyto what is this white dialog that you talk about? The actionbar?

Comment: Sorry to bother, but it seams that this screen only appears when started directly from Eclipse. When run from "icon" or on the phone, it does not appear. 

Not sure if that is normal thing, or is the Emulation from Eclips slower and it results with blank screen but it does for some reason.